# verifyReleaseResources apk release - react native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to release my apk with this command:

```
sudo ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

but I got this error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-contacts:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

my react versions:

```
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "0.55.4",
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

solved.

add this to the end of android/build.gradle file:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is smooth :)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, add the following lines of code in your ***android/build.gradle*** file

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work in your case then run the following command for a temporary solution

> ./gradlew app:assembleRelease